# Unity to WebGL: Error only when deploying "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: javascript, firebase, unity-game-engine

[image]

Apparently this error is in the default UnityLoader.js that Unity spits out. I haven't had this problem before, and Im hosting using Firebase.

What is wrong here and how can I fix this SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' error?

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the error itself? What additional information did the JS console provide you?

Comment: On the JS console it  usually means trying to get a response from the server, but it redirect to a 404 page or something so you're not getting a valid JSON (because the response is HTML)

Comment: @AlonEitan I need to use openweatherapi so I changed the http to an https - what would be a way around this?

Comment: well is that API reachable under `http` or `https`? If it doesn't listen on https than why did you change it? Just stick with `http` if that worked .. as far as I saw all API URLs in the docu there use `http`

Comment: @AlonEitan nice catch ;)

Comment: @derHugo Sorry, no apparently its only http but Firebase only allows from https. What would you suggest?

Comment: Hard to tell without you providing any code or how exactly you are using the URL.